# Iterated parameters with paginated datatable and ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable

I'm trying to find solution for problem with datatable/ajax (in short):

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="ptl-body" id="toRender">
<h:dataTable value="#{flightMBean.flights}" var="f" id="flight_table" styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Airline</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{f.airline.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    ...
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
        <span class="label label-success">Approved </span>
        <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN">
            <h:form>
                <h:commandButton action="#{userMBean.observeFlight(f.id)}"
                                 styleClass="btn purple" value="Observe">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </sec:authorize>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Paginator actions:

```
<h:form style="margin: 0 0 0 0">
<h:commandButton  styleClass="btn"
                  action="#{flightMBean.previous()}" 
                  rendered="#{flightMBean.paginator.hasPreviousPage}"
                  value="Prev">
    <f:ajax render=":toRender"/>
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton styleClass="btn" action="#{flightMBean.next()}" 
                 rendered="#{flightMBean.paginator.hasNextPage}"
                 value="Next">
    <f:ajax render=":toRender"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

For the first view page of datatable everything seems to be working. When I click 'Observe' flight with good id goes to database. Problem appears when I click 'Next' button - datatable renders with new rows but every id is the same like on the first page.

For example on the first page I have fligh: from x to y at 20:00 with id=1
and another with id=2, second page renders with third flight with id=3.
If i want to observe first or second flight everything is ok!
If i want to observe third, flight with id=1 goes to database.

PS.
If i put just #{f.id} without form/commandButton/jsf components everything looks good... just jsf components resets my parameters ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will happen if the backing bean is request scoped and doesn't preserve exactly the same data model (the object behind `<h:dataTable value>`) during (post)construction.

Either put the bean in the view scope, or write logic in bean's (post)constructor to preserve exactly the same data model as it was when the form with the table is presented to the enduser. If it depends on some request based conditions, then you can use `<f:param>` to retain them across requests.

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - point 4.

Comment: It's the answer I was waiting for! I changed scope of my bean from default request to view scoped and everything is going on my road at this moment :P